# How to make a loop when file already exists in path

Tags: android

Making one voice recording app,here after recording voice file saving in SD card ,here is my code to save file to sdcard ,here i am specifying file name so that only one recording is possible ,i want to make a loop for this by getting filename from user ,how to make a loop for storing all filenames.help me

```
 public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {

    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    stopButton.setEnabled(true);

    File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try {
        audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", sampleDir);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
        return;
    }
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
}
```

Saving to Sd card

```
 protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand.
Do you mean you want to know how to save your TempFile "sound.3gp" under a new name that the user supplies? If so:

```
try {
    InputStream dataIn = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
    OutputStream dataOut = new FileOutputStream(userFile);

    // copy the data from the temp file to the new user file
    byte[] myBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead= dataIn.read(myBuffer)) > 0) {
        dataOut.write(myBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
} finally {
    dataIn.close();
    dataOut.close();
}
```

**`<Additional>`**
If you want to get the user to enter a file name, and then record the audio directly to that file then you could do the following:

```
// Get the file name from the user
String usersFileName = usersFileNameEditText.getText().toString() + ".3gp";

// Replace any blank spaces they may have put in their file name
usersFileName.replace(" ", "\\");

// Create the file
File sampleDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
try {
    File usersFile = new File(sampleDir, audiofile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
    return;
}

// Record the audio
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
recorder.prepare();
recorder.start();
...
```

Note that because you are allowing the user to specify their own file name, you will probably want to check if a file with the same name has already been saved in the current directory, so adjust your code.

```
...
if (audiofile.exists()) {
    // A file with this name already exists.
    // Ask the user if they want to continue and overwrite the existing file.
    // or enter a different file name.
} else {
    // File does not already exist so go ahead and start the recording
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
    ...
}
...
```

Comment: Hard to understand??problem : i can able to save one audio file in SD card using above code but if i tried to save again then problem with my code ,because i m giving static value for name ,so want to make a condition to store all voice recording audio files how to do it,this is my max english;-)

Comment: That makes it clearer. Thank you. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I can't speak any foreign languages well enough to talk about programming, so you're doing better than me there!  :-)